# Using manual’s example code for writing a `UI` subclass in Vaadin Flow

Tags: java, web-applications, view, vaadin, vaadin-flow

On the page of the manual for [*Differences Between V10 and V8 Applications*](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/migration/3-general-differences.html), there is this example code for those who want to write a `UI` subclass as we did in Vaadin 8, despite being no longer required in [Vaadin Flow](https://vaadin.com/flow).

(changing the original mydomain-dot-com to `example.com` to appease the Stack Overflow censor robot)

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "myservlet", asyncSupported = true,
// Example on initialization parameter configuration
initParams = {
        @WebInitParam(name = "frontend.url.es6", value = "http://example.com/es6/"),
        @WebInitParam(name = "frontend.url.es5", value = "http://example.com/es5/") })
// The UI configuration is optional
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
public class MyServlet extends VaadinServlet {
}

// this is not necessary anymore, but might help you get started with migration
public class MyUI extends UI {
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        // do initial steps here.
        // previously routing
    }
}
```

Syntactically that is either incorrect or is meant to be written into two separate `.java` files.

Or should the `MyServlet` class be set within the `MyUI` class, as was done by default in Vaadin 8? Like this:

```
package com.raddkit;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.UI;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletConfiguration;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

public class MyUI extends UI {
    protected void init ( VaadinRequest request ) {

    }

    @WebServlet ( urlPatterns = "/*", name = "myservlet", asyncSupported = true,
        // Example on initialization parameter configuration
        initParams = {
            @WebInitParam ( name = "frontend.url.es6", value = "http://example.com/es6/" ) ,
            @WebInitParam ( name = "frontend.url.es5", value = "http://example.com/es5/" ) } )
    // The UI configuration is optional
    @VaadinServletConfiguration ( ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false )
    public class MyServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange, true. But I would just do separate files.

Answer (score 0):

That example is meant to be written into two separate .java files. Alternatively, you can define the servlet as a public **static** inner class, enclosed in a UI class. In that case, the `ui` attribute of `@VaadinServletConfiguration` defaults to the enclosing UI.